# What kind of energy remains after rock erosion?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, material-science

Please explain like I am five. To my understanding, energy from the sun is converted into kinetic energy (wind, water) which eventually erodes solid material (rocks) into smaller particles (sand). What does the kinetic energy convert into?

Would it be theoretically possible to revert this process and extract energy? I.e. by merging sand particles into rock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the energy ends up dissipated as heat.

Over time scales similar to those of rock erosion, the particles can indeed be turned into rock again, when they are deposited in a area (for example, by water) and cemented, forming the so-called [sedimentary rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedimentary_rock).

Trying to turn sand to rock (or glass) more quickly, though, typically requires (instead of release) large amounts of energy.